# Emulate string split() from Javascript Object Oriented Programing Stoyan Stefanov book

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, oop

Im learning JS OOP from Stoyan Stefanov's book. I got problem with exercise 4 in chapter 4:

> Imagine the String()constructor didn't exist. Create a constructor
>   function MyString()that acts like String()as closely as possible.
>   You're not allowed to use any built-in string methods or properties,
>   and remember that String()doesn't exist. You can use this code to test
>   your constructor:

Below is my attempt for creating String split() like method. Could you guide me how to make it work ?

```js
function MineString(string){
    this.lengthS = string.length;
    //this[1] = "test";
    for(var i = 0; i < string.length;i++){
        this[i] = string.charAt(i);    
    }

    this.toString = function(){
        return string;
    }

    this.split = function(char){
        var splitedArray = [];
        var foundedChar = [];
        var string2 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.lengthS ; i++){
            foundedChar.push(string[i].indexOf(char)); 
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < foundedChar.length; j++){
            if(foundedChar[j] === -1){
                //splitedArray[0] += string.charAt(j);
                //splitedArray[j] = string.charAt(j);
                string2 += string.charAt(j);
                //splitedArray.push(string2);
                splitedArray[foundedChar.length] = string2;
            }else if (foundedChar[j] === 0){
                //splitedArray.push(string.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        
        return splitedArray;        
    }

}

var text = new MineString("hello");
text.split("e");
```

So text.split("e"); should display something like this:

```js
var text = new MineString("hello");
    text.split("e");
    ["h","llo"]
```

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten the rules at the first line of your constructor function ; ).

Comment: split may contain only one character or it can be more

Comment: Result of this: 
var text = new MineString("hello");
text.split("e");
Should look like this:
["h","llo"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split method looks somehow overly complicated. I simplified it and rewrote the other parts of your class so that they adhere to the task of not using string methods. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j10forhj/) or the code below.

New JS-Code:

```
function MineString(str){
    this.str = str;

    this.addChar = function(c) {
        this.str += c;
    }

    this.length = function() {
        return this.str.length;
    }

    this.toString = function(){
        return this.str;
    }

    this.split = function(char){
        var out = [],
            current = new MineString(""),
            addCurrent = function() {
                if (current.length() > 0) {
                    out.push(current.toString());
                    current = new MineString("");
                }
            };

        for (i = 0; i < this.str.length; i++) {
            if (this.str[i] == char) {
                addCurrent();
            } else {
                current.addChar(this.str[i]);
            }
        }

        addCurrent();

        return out;      
    }

}

var text = new MineString("hello");
console.log(text.split("e"));
```

Outputs:

```
["h", "llo"]
```

Comment: I though mine is overly complicated :). Thanks for your help - that is exactly what I was looking for.